# English teacher's question about subject of a sentence

Tags: subjects

My students and I have a disagreement about the subject of the following sentence:
"Many animals were found on the farm."
I say it's "Many"; they say it's "animals." Who's right?

Comment: "Many" just modifies "animals", so it can't be an object

Comment: Dixie, if you are a teacher, you might be interested in ell.stackexchange.com where you can pose questions on how to teach English. Please, take a look. Thank you.

Comment: ELL is for non-native speakers. Dixie didn't say she was teaching ESL. Dixie, I'd be interested in your theory about why it should be _many_. BTW, camelbrush has it correct below, so you and your students are both wrong; a subject has to be a noun phrase, but not necessarily a single word.

Answer (score 5):

*Many animals* would be the (complete) subject in your sentence, with *many* being the modifier. Have a look at this page [here](http://english---language.blogspot.com/2006/04/grammer-subject-and-predicate.html) to get more such examples and the different types of subjects.
 And as #Carlo_R suggested, have a look at the ell.stackexchange.com page for further help especially while teaching.

Answer (score -1):

Pls make the distinction between the following sentences

> Animals were found on the farm.
>   Many animals were found on the farm.
>   Few animals were found on the farm.

If for any reason, you and your students are able to justify that they convey the same message, then you have a strong case that

> Animals were found on the farm.

is sufficient.